# Gwt CellTable Sorting page by page only

Tags: sorting, gwt, celltable

GWT `CellTable` column sorting page by page only, for each page i have to click the column header
for sorting.
How to sort whole data on single header click.
This is my code,

```java
   dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<List<NamePair>>();
   dataProvider.addDataDisplay(dgrid);
   List<List<NamePair>> list = dataProvider.getList();

   for (List<NamePair> contact : test) {
      dataProvider.setList(test);
      list.add(contact);
   }


   ListHandler<List<NamePair>> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<List<NamePair>>(dataProvider.getList());
   System.out.println("Column count->"+dgrid.getColumnCount());

   for(int j=0 ; j<dgrid.getColumnCount();j++){             
        final int val = j;
        columnSortHandler.setComparator(dgrid.getColumn(val), new Comparator<List<NamePair>>() {

        public int compare(List<NamePair> o1, List<NamePair> o2) {
          if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
         }

         // Compare the column.
         if (o1 != null) {
            int index = val;
            return (o2 != null) ? o1.get(index-2).compareTo(o2.get(index-2)) : 1;
         }
         return -1;
        }
    });
}

dgrid.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you override `ListHandler` , override and call `super.onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent)` to  debug the `onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent)` method, you'll understand what is happening very fast.

The source code of the method is pretty direct

```java
public void onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent event) {
  // Get the sorted column.
  Column<?, ?> column = event.getColumn();
  if (column == null) {
    return;
  }

  // Get the comparator.
  final Comparator<T> comparator = comparators.get(column);
  if (comparator == null) {
    return;
  }

  // Sort using the comparator.
  if (event.isSortAscending()) {
    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
  } else {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<T>() {
      public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return -comparator.compare(o1, o2);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The only reason why you override ListHandler, is to isolate this table from the others (and avoid having the debugger triggered many times) you can naturally put your breakpoint directly in that method if your project is simple